# dotCover with Teamcity 8.0.4 on windows server 2012 will not start build agent

Tags: nunit, teamcity, dotcover

Whn I try to run a NUnit and dotCover test with these settings:

[image: NUnit build configuration]

Teamcity tells me "*Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration.
Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.*".

When I go to the build queue, and look at the Incompatible agents, I end up with this:

[image: Incompatible build agent reason]

I have installed .NET 3.5 on the server. I have even tried downloading the doCover trial, but no matter what. I get the same result. Teamcity would not run my tests.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Am I specifing the wrong things in the configuration of NUnit? When I not doing coverage the unit test runs fine.

**UPDATE**
I installed .NET 3.5 using server manager (add roles and so on). The agent is running on the same server as the teamcity server. In the c:\windows\microsoft.net I have a Framework\v3.5 folder and a Framwork64\v3.5 folder.

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing .NET Framework?

Comment: Yes. It has been restartet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. I just tried to restart my server again, and it worked. Maybe the order I did it in was wrong? I installed .NET 3.5, restarted and then installed TeamCity. I should have installed .NET 3.5, then TeamCity and then restarted the server.

Answer (score 1):

A few questions
1. Is the agent running in the same machine as the teamcity server?

1. Did you install .net framework 3.5 using the platform installer or via a download?
2. Can you see a .net 3.5 framework folder in c:\windows\microsoft.net?

Comment: I installed it using server manager (add roles and so on). The agent is running on the same server as the teamcity server. In the c:\windows\microsoft.net I have a Framework\v3.5 folder and a Framwork64\v3.5 folder. I have added this comment to my question.